# USB booting not working

Tags: windows-8, boot, installation, operating-systems

I want to install windows 8 using pen drive but it does not detect pen drive which i have make it bootable.
I have sony vaio VPCEB34EN laptop.

It boots from DVD writer but not from USB pen drive at boot time.

Any one suggest me how can i install windows 8 from pen drive  and boot it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On some Sony notebooks you need to disable the Bios "Fast Boot" option in order to be able to boot from USB.
Also, check booting from an USB port located on the other side (most of the times they use different controllers). On one weird Vaio notebook just one of the usb ports worked for booting.

Hope this helps

Comment: Also some USB pen drive may be detected as HDD. So check your boot as it may not be shown under Boot from USB, but Boot from HDD. If your Sony laptop have a One-Time Boot, try using that and aim to your USB drive.